# Using Torricelli's Law to find how long it takes for a vertical tub to drain

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A tub of water with vertical sides is draining. By Torricelli's principle, the rate of decrease in the amount of water is proportional to the square root of the amount of water. Let $M(t)$ be the amount of water after $t$ minutes and suppose that $M(10)$ is one half of $M(0)$. When is the tub empty?

So I set up the DE to be $M'(t) = k\sqrt{M(t)}$, and we also have $M(10)=0.5M(0)$. I'm having trouble finding the rate constant $k$ here. I've tried using the M.V.T, but I still end up with too many unknowns to have anything fruitful. I feel like the end goal is going to be something like $\frac{0-M(0)}{t-0}=k\sqrt{M(0)}$ and then I solve for t, though I feel that I might be thinking too algebraically about this problem. Any help or advice is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the problem doesn't explicitly ask you to find all the constants. It's actually not possible to do that, since there aren't enough conditions. The actual question is: **When is the tub empty?**

With that in mind, let's try to solve for $M$ first:

$$ \frac{M'}{\sqrt{M}} = -k $$

where the negative sign denotes a negative rate of change. Integrating both sides gives

$$ 2\sqrt{M} = c - kt $$
$$ M(t) = \frac{(c-kt)^2}{4} $$

where $c$ is another arbitrary constant.

Now the question asks: **For which value of $t$ is $M(t) = 0$?**

Answer: It occurs when $t = \frac{c}{k}$. So we just need to find this ratio.

Using the remaining condition, we have

$$ \frac{M(10)}{M(0)} = \frac{(c-10k)^2}{c^2} = \frac{1}{2} $$

$$ \implies \frac{c-10k}{c} = 1 - \frac{10k}{c} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} $$ 
$$ \implies \frac{10k}{c} = 1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{\sqrt{2}} $$
$$ \implies \frac{c}{k} = \frac{10\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}-1} $$